# jQuery options for created HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, documentation

Hi can someone point me in the direction of the documentation that specifies what options are available for elements created with jQuery? like class, text, click etc

e.g.

```
myelement = $("<select/>",
{
    "class":     "myclass",
    click:  function(){
        console.log(this.value);
    },
    onchange?: function(){
        console.log("don't know the syntax for this");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

> As of jQuery 1.4, the second argument to jQuery() can accept a map consisting of a superset of **the properties that can be passed to the .attr() method**. Furthermore, **any event type can be passed in**, and the following jQuery methods can be called: **val, css, html, text, data, width, height, or offset**. The name "class" must be quoted in the map since it is a JavaScript reserved word, and "className" cannot be used since it is not the correct attribute name.

This means:

1. Any attribute such as `href` or `src`
2. Any event such as `click` or `mouseover`
3. Properties named `text`, `html`, `data`, `width`, `height` or `offset` work just like the corresponding jQuery methods with the same name.

In your case you need to use the event name: `change` instead of `onchange`.

Answer (score 1):

A select element is subject to all of the [**Form Events**](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/form-events/) and the [**Mouse Events**](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/) and [**Keyboard Events**](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/) as wells as the standard HTML attributes.

---

Typically, you'll use the name, class, id, style, title and tabindex HTML attributes.
The events that I've most commonly used and seen used with a select object (most form objects) are the click, hover (used with .toggle()), mouseleave/mouseenter (instead of hover/.toggle()).

---

### [HTML Attributes](http://www.quackit.com/html/tags/html_select_tag.cfm) http://www.quackit.com/html/tags/html_select_tag.cfm

- **name**
- **size**
- **multiple** Specifies that multiple selections can be made.
- **class**
- **id**
- **dir** Specifies the direction of the text
- **lang** Language code
- **style** Inline style (CSS)
- **title** Specifies a title to associate with the element.
- **tabindex** Helps determine the tabbing order (when the user 'tabs'
  through the elements on the page).
- **disabled** Disables the input control. The button won't accept changes
  from the user. It also cannot receive focus and will be skipped when
  tabbing.

---

### [Keyboard Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/) http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/

- **focusin**
- **focusout**
- **keydown**
- **keypress**
- **keyup**

---

### [Mouse Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/) http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

- **click**
- **dblclick**
- **focusin**
- **focusout**
- **hover**
- **mousedown**
- **mouseenter**
- **mouseleave**
- **mousemove**
- **mouseout**
- **mouseover**
- **mouseup**
- **toggle**

---

### [Form Events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/form-events/) http://api.jquery.com/category/events/form-events/

- **blur**
- **change**
- **focus**
- **select**
- **submit**

---

On top of all this, there's quite a bit of CSS attributes that can be applied to the element.. but that list would double the length of this post so I'll refrain from posting them.